# Create a chat like in Ada in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, chat, chatbot

I'm new to programming, so please be patient. I'd like to implement in my current app a chat, but not with other users, but rather with the app itself. In the app called "Ada" the way user interacts with the app is through various buttons that he presses, after which the app gives the answer. So, as far as I understand what I try to create has nothing to do with machine learning, so I'd like to avoid such services as DialogFlow or the same service provided by IBM, as I don't want to pay for the additional features that I will never use (I don't want my users to use keyboard input to interact with the app, I want them to use only buttons). But I'd like to create a page, which looks like a chat. The only app that I know that has implemented exactly what I need is Ada. The problem is that there is literally no page on that topic on the Internet, so I don't know where to even begin. As I don't know where to even start, I have no starting code to provide you with.
Here is a simple example of what I mean:

[image]

On the right the app gives the user a test, as user pressed "begin" button
Hope that you understand what I need and you'd help me a lot if you would explain exactly how to create such a chat.

Comment: This is an iOS question, not a Swift question. You should add the iOS tag.

Comment: And it's awfully open-ended for a forum like this.

Comment: I'd suggest using a table view. Each entry in the chat would be a new cell, and could create question cells, yes/no button cells, and possibleAnswer cells. You'd keep adding cells to your data source as the user progressed through the chat.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a Udemy course on this very subject:

https://www.udemy.com/course/simple-ios-chat-app-in-swift-4-firebase-4/?LSNPUBID=VkwVKCHWj2A&siteID=VkwVKCHWj2A-wV3kGNSueSCVcV8Oj.3Qxw&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DSA_Catchall_la.EN_cc.US&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_95911180068_._ad_436639626698_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-402185414521_._li_9059739_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-uSro4KM6gIVCYizCh3XiwKLEAAYASAAEgL81PD_BwE

Comment: Thank you for you answer! The problem is that there are a lot of such articles and courses, but I didn't find any of them where you don't interact with real people, but rather with the app itself. This particular one helps to create a group chat with real people, which doesn't suit my app

Comment: It's almost always the case that you'll need to adapt tutorials/sample code to your specific needs. This is an example of that.